# Best way to merge two Xcode projects

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to merge 2 Xcode projects. Each of these projects are full functional apps & available on appStore. Each app has some custom frameworks already included into them like lumberjack, hockey. I do not want to use cocoa pods.

Comment: Can you provide some details about what exactly you want to merge? full screens? functions, functionality...?

Comment: I want to convert my iOS app into a framework which uses a third-party framework... Then I want to use this converted framework into another ios app.